# не могу сделать проверку лида на дубликат

Tags: php, битрикс

С стороннего ресурса, в crm битрикс24 делаю создание лида:

```
$paramspost = 'LOGIN='.$login.'&PASSWORD='.$pass.'&STATUS_ID='.$status.'&ASSIGNED_BY_NAME='.$kad.'&TITLE='.$numer.'&COMMENTS=&UF_CRM_1425370307='.$summa.'&COMPANY_TITLE='.$name.'&ADDRESS='.$adress.'&PHONE_MOBILE='.$tel.'&CRM_LEAD_EDIT_V12_active_tab=tab_1&UF_CRM_1448875873=&SOURCE_ID=SELF';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://домен.bitrix24.ru/crm/configs/import/lead.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramspost);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Length: '.strlen($paramspost),
'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
'Expires: ' . date("r")
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$bx24result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

а вот как проверить, перед созданием, существует ли такой лид, незнаю

Comment: можно попробовать перед созданием проверять методом `CCrmLead::GetList()` http://bxapi.ru/src/?module_id=crm&name=CCrmLead::GetList наличие по полям наименование, email, телефон.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению не нашел событие до добавления Лида ([список событий](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/crm/crm_events.php)). Можно конечно через событие OnAfterCrmLeadAdd проверять старые такие же, по названию и удалять их, но это плохо.
Лучше конечно сделать свой импортирующий скрипт, который через CCrmLead::GetList будет находить похожие по нужным вам параметрам и решать, добавлять новый лид или нет.